# "Response has already been written" with Vertx

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x

I am brand new to Vertx and trying to create my first HTTP Rest Server. However, I have been running into this issue. Here is the error I'm getting when I try to send a response.

```
Jan 07, 2017 3:54:36 AM io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase
SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.checkWritten(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:559)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.putHeader(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:156)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.putHeader(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:54)
    at com.themolecule.utils.Response.sendResponse(Response.kt:25)
    at com.themolecule.api.UserAPI.addUser(UserAPI.kt:52)
    at TheMoleculeAPI$main$3.handle(TheMoleculeAPI.kt:50)
    at TheMoleculeAPI$main$3.handle(TheMoleculeAPI.kt:19)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:215)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:94)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.AuthHandlerImpl.authorise(AuthHandlerImpl.java:86)
    at
```

And this is how I have set up my routes.

```
// setup verx
        val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
        val router = Router.router(vertx)

        val allowHeaders = HashSet<String>()
        allowHeaders.add("x-requested-with")
        allowHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        allowHeaders.add("origin")
        allowHeaders.add("Content-Type")
        allowHeaders.add("accept")
        val allowMethods = HashSet<HttpMethod>()
        allowMethods.add(HttpMethod.GET)
        allowMethods.add(HttpMethod.POST)
        allowMethods.add(HttpMethod.DELETE)
        allowMethods.add(HttpMethod.PATCH)

        router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("*")
                .allowedHeaders(allowHeaders)
                .allowedMethods(allowMethods))

        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create())

        val config = JsonObject().put("keyStore", JsonObject()
                .put("path", "keystore.jceks")
                .put("type", "jceks")
                .put("password", "password"))

        // protect the API, login outside of JWT
        router.route("/them/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwt, "/them/login"))

        //login routes
        router.post("/them/login").handler { it -> loginAPI.login(it, jwt) }

        //user routes
        router.get("/them/user/getusers").handler { it -> userAPI.getUsers(it) }
        router.post("/them/user/addUser").handler { it -> userAPI.addUser(it) }
```

This is the code that it seems to have the problem with.

```
fun sendResponse(responseCode: Int, responseMsg: String, context: RoutingContext) {
        val userResponse = JsonObject().put("response", responseMsg)
        context
                .response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .setStatusCode(responseCode)
                .end(userResponse.encodePrettily())
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong with the handlers? I tried to change the method for the response up a bunch of times, but nothing seems to work. This is written in Kotlin. If I need to add more context, just say the word!

edit: addUser method added

```
fun addUser(context: RoutingContext) {
        val request = context.bodyAsJson
        val newUser = NewUserRequestDTO(request.getString("userID").trim(), request.getString("password").trim())

        newUser.userID.trim()
        if (!newUser.userID.isNullOrEmpty() && !newUser.password.isNullOrEmpty()) {

            //check user ID
            if (userDAO.userIdInUse(newUser.userID)) {
                Response.sendResponse(400, Response.ResponseMessage.ID_IN_USE.message, context)
                return
            }

            //check password valid
            val isValid: Boolean = SecurityUtils.checkPasswordCompliance(newUser.password)
            if (!isValid) {
                Response.sendResponse(400, Response.ResponseMessage.PASSWORD_IS_NOT_VALID.message, context)
                return
            }

            val saltedPass = SecurityUtils.genSaltedPasswordAndSalt(newUser.password)
            userDAO.addUser(newUser.userID, saltedPass.salt.toString(), saltedPass.pwdDigest.toString())
        } else {
            Response.sendResponse(401, Response.ResponseMessage.NO_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD.message, context)
            return
        }

        Response.sendResponse(200, Response.ResponseMessage.USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY.message, context)
    }
```

Comment: What does your addUser() looks like?

Comment: @alexey-soshin I believe I fixed it by adding return after each response. From what I can tell because of how my conditional statements are, it would always trickle down to the 200 response. I had assumed the .end() would break out of the method, but obviously that's not how it works. So by returning it does that. I added the addUser() though